# Bool vector if value in list pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Its easy to create a vector of bools in pandas for testing values such as

```
DF['a'] > 10
```

but how do you write

```
DF['a'] in list
```

to generate a vector of bools based on membership of each value in the Series in some list or other? I am getting a value error.

I know I can loop through the data pretty simply, but is this possible without having to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `isin` method:

```
DF['a'].isin(list)
```

Example:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5),'b':np.arange(5)*2})
print DF

   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  2
2  2  4
3  3  6
4  4  8

print DF['a'].isin([0,2,3])

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
```